# Binding ListView inside combobox item not binding(showing)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, prism

I'm trying to create a Combobox with multiple items and header and way I'm approaching is to create a `listView` (or `DataGrid`) inside the Combobox 
but for some reason, the items won't bind

as you can see no items in the list
[image]

**XAML** (when ComboBox.ItemTemplate have used the items showed properly with no headers of course)

```
  <ComboBox                        
                            materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="בחר מתכון מהרשימה">
                                  <!--ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Recipes}"  >-->
                                  <!--DisplayMemberPath = "Description">-->


                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Recipes}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedRecipe}"
                         Height="200" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsEnabled="False" Focusable="False">
                                <ListView.View>
                                    <GridView>
                                        <GridViewColumn Width="130"  Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"   />                                      
                                    </GridView>
                                </ListView.View>
                            </ListView>

                        </ComboBox>
```

**ViewModel** (im using `Prism` as my MVVM library)

```
 public ObservableCollection<Recipes> Recipes
        {
            get { return _recipes; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _recipes, value); }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Recipes> _recipes = new ObservableCollection<Recipes>();

        private async void FillRecipesList() //this is call on program startup
        {
            if (Recipes != null && Recipes.Count > 0)
            {
                Recipes.Clear(); 
            }
            var result = await _mSql.GetRecipes();
            if (result.Count() > 0)
                Recipes.AddRange(result);
        }
```

**Model**

```
 public class Recipes
    {
        public long AutoNum { get; set; }
        public int? RecipeCode { get; set; }
        public int? RecipeVersion { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: @dymanoid edited my question and added a picture for better understanding

Comment: Does it work if you move the `ListView` out of the `ComboBox`? Why are you using a `ComboBox` in the first place?

Comment: Please provide a complete example. The ComboBox is located in a XAML file of some kind: A UserControl, Window, Page, something. `Recipes` is a member of some class that you call a viewmodel. An instance of that viewmodel should be the DataContext of the view that contains the ComboBox. If that is the case, and if there are any items in the `Recipes` collection, the ListView will populate correctly (I tested it). Therefore, at least one of those things isn't true. But it's a short list. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to call the method

```
FillRecipesList()
```

in your ViewModel's constructor

Comment: It is called and the list is populated